# List<T> submit form binding in MVC5

Tags: model, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I am fairly new to MVC5. So far I seem to have searched my way through into solving my issues, however, I've come across a problem that I cannot figure out the solution.

I am creating two Views, one for creating a new Article Post, and one for Editing current Article Posts.

My article model is as follows:

```
public class Article
{
    private int? _id;

    [BsonRequired]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [BsonElement("_id")]
    public int? Id
    {
        get { return _id ?? 999999; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    ...
    [HiddenInput]
    [BsonElement("related")]
    public List<Related> Related { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput]
    [BsonElement("comments")]
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput]
    [BsonElement("auto_publish")]
    public AutoPublish AutoPublish { get; set; }

}
}
```

My issue is with Lists of Model Items (like `List<Comment>`, `List<Related>`) and the custom Model property.

In my Post and Edit views, i have set @Html.HiddenFor attributes for all of my model properties, but I am having a particularly hard time to **NOT** lose values for my custom model properties (like AutoPublish) and my list of model properties.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but for List of string items, I have used the following logic:

```
     for (var i = 0; i < Model.Categories.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Categories[i])
}
```

For the other custom Lists, I tried creating a DisplayTemplate, with the following code:

```
@model List<CMS.Models.Comment>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.Date)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.Email)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.Enabled)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.Ip)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.Username)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.PostId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.Text)
}
```

However, when I try to use @Html.DisplayForModel("Comments", Model.Comments) within my View, I get a model type mismatch.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?
Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: What does the using statement at the top of your view look like?

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Editor", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form-edit-post" }))
This is what the using looks like

Comment: Is that the very first line in your view?

Comment: No, this is the very first line @model CMS.Models.Article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DisplayForModel` is specific to the view's model. You can't pass any random object into it. You're probably looking for `DisplayFor(m => m.Comments)`, but bear in mind that when you pass an enumerable to `DisplayFor`, it actually renders the display template for *each* item in the collection. In other words, you need to remove the `foreach` in your partial view, and change the model declaration to a single `Comment` instead of a `List<Comment>`.

**EDIT**

Actually, since you're rendering `HiddenInput`s this should be an *editor* template, and you should be using `EditorFor`. `DisplayFor` is only for, well, display. Everything else I said still applies with `EditorFor`.

Comment: Thanks for your time @Chris Pratt. I have removed the foreach from the (now) EditorTemplate, removed the List and using a single Comment, and now using @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Comments, "Comments"). However, since in my Article model Comments is a List of Comments, I still get a model mismatch, saying that the dictionary requires a single Comment instead of a List. Should I use a for loop for each Comment? Just like i do in Lists of strings?

Comment: That's probably because you're passing an explicit editor template reference. Just call `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Comments)` and make sure you have an editor template whose name matches exactly the class name  for a single instance, presumably `Comment`. Razor will take care of the rest. If you pass an explicit template to use, then Razor  steps out of the way and makes you responsible for everything, so you actually *would* need that foreach in your template. However, doing it that way pretty much defeats the entire purpose of `EditorFor`. You might as well just put the code right in the view.

Comment: Thanks again Chris. Just to make it clear: I have an html helper as so @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Comments), I have a Comment.cshtml in ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates. My Comment.cshtml is a bunch of HiddenFor for my 6 properties within Comment and using a model of Comment.

Comment: And by using the above, viewing the page source, I can see now this:`System.Collections.Generic.List1[CMS.Models.Comment]<input id="Comments" name="Comments" type="hidden" value="System.Collections.Generic.List1[CMS.Models.Comment]" />` and I get a Model validation Error `{"The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'CMS.Models.Comment' failed because no type converter can convert between these types."}`

Comment: As it's most of the case, this was a human error (aka mine). In my effort to make this work prior to posting this question, I had left out `[HiddenInput]` for my `List<T>`, which in turn was rendering a hidden input field as mentioned above. Removing that attribute makes this work correctly. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction Chris. Seems like I have LOT to learn about MVC still to become competant.

Comment: Don't worry about it. There's a lot to learn. I've been working with MVC for 3 years and I still learn new things all the time. Working with a language or framework never produces some magic moment where you suddenly know everything. It's always a gradual incline of improving your skills over time. We all started out at the bottom.